# OptaPlanner, Score calculation speed will be too low

Tags: optaplanner

Run my optaplanner project and got following output. Seems there are two issues. What do these output mean? The first is

```
Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread ({})'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
```

and the other one is

```
ERROR 603112 --- [pool-1-thread-3] o.o.core.impl.solver.thread.ThreadUtils  : Multithreaded Local Search's ExecutorService didn't terminate within timeout (1 seconds).
```

the output that contains the errors is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dXX9O_3DDDBgMksoEdbmAbDbXynfMEouYYmtl8iVD6E/edit?usp=sharing).

the application.properties is copied from somewhere, don't understand it much. the file is like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:fedb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.drools=INFO
logging.level.org.optaplanner.core=INFO
optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=2s
optaplanner.solver.move-thread-count=10
optaplanner.solver.environment-mode=NON_REPRODUCIBLE
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500MB
server.port=8090
```

To answer Geoffrey's questions:
Using Java 1.8.0_241, OptaPlanner optaplanner-bom 7.59.0.Final.
The terminate time is set to 2 seconds, the app exits on time with a working solution. The error output can be reproduced all the time yesterday, but no error at all today, no code change. Really strange. Today's output is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ky2HCZMO5T8uqjN4vHpKwRSUUxWPSw72fdIjm1EoKx0/edit?usp=sharing). I think I should delete the post.

Answer (score 2):

On top of Geoffrey's answer, I want to point out one more thing from the log you provided:

```
 The resolvedMoveThreadCount (10) is higher than the availableProcessorCount (8), which is counter-efficient.
```

You seem to be over-extending your machine. All that context switching may be grinding your solvers to a halt.

Furthermore, I believe the current best practice is to not go above 4 move threads, as the solver likely won't scale past that anyway.

Comment: Thank you Lukáš. I updated my post with more information and the error is gone today without any reason.

Comment: Could it be a _live lock_? I doubt it: if the move threads take all the execution time, they drain the operations queue and block, giving the other move threads and the solver thread a chance to run (and create new operations). On the other hand... if 8 of the 10 move threads live lock the other two, what would happen? There are checkYielding() calls, but is a runnableThreadSemaphore defined to actually yield? On the other hand, the operations queue will drain, forcing those 8 threads to block.
I need to see the TRACE log.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. It smells like an exotic bug.

The CH didn't have enough time finish, even though it got more than 10+ minutes:

```
  INFO Solving started: time spent (12), ...
 ERROR Multithreaded Local Search's ExecutorService didn't terminate within timeout (1 seconds).
  INFO Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread ({})'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough.
  ...
  INFO Construction Heuristic ... ended: time spent (682760), ..., step total (1).
  INFO Solving ended: time spent (682760), ...
```

More worryingly, **the CH did even finish the first step in 10+ minutes**!

1. Does this reproduce in every run? I see NON_REPRODUCIBLE is configured.
2. Does this reproduce with moveThreadCount=NONE ?
3. Any clue in `TRACE` logging?
4. Which OptaPlanner version?

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. I updated my post with more information and the error is gone today without any reason.

Comment: It's not gone. It will happen again.
It's either 1) a rare case that only triggers with a specific random seed. Or  instead 2) a race condition. Put the `environmentMode=REPRODICBLE` (this will make it use a specific random seed) and if that doesn't reproduce, set the randomSeed explicitly in the solverConfig.xml and run it 10 times with 10 different random seeds (0, 1, 2, etc).

Comment: How to turn on TRACE logging? with 7.59.0.Final. Googled but didn't get it.

Comment: See docs, in the TOC search bar, look for "logging". It's a section in chapter 5 IIRC.

Comment: We're fixing the googling of our docs.