# Implications of "Score calculation speed will be too low"

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, optaplanner

Possibly related: [OptaPlanner, Score calculation speed will be too low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201962/optaplanner-score-calculation-speed-will-be-too-low)

I am receiving the `SEVERE` log

> Multithreaded Local Search's ExecutorService didn't terminate within timeout (1 seconds)

and immediately after get the `INFO` log

> Score calculation speed will be too low because move thread (#)'s destroy wasn't processed soon enough

for each move thread.  There are 96 which I recognize is far more than the reccomended max of 4, but our bottle-neck is single-threaded heavy-duty math.  The context switching is not significant.

Our domain model has some rather expensive calculations and it's not surprising that we see some score change calculations taking a while to complete (> 1s).  I know it's not good, but we're handling it and it is unrelated to OptaPlanner.

My question is about the implications of specifically

> Score calculation speed will be too low

Does that mean that the *reported value* will be lower than it actually was?  Or is it the case that score calculation will actually be slower after this is logged due to issues with the threads not terminating cleanly?  Or something else?

Comment: Although I am not the author of the code in question, my understanding of this message was always in general terms. The speed will be too low to get anything useful done. If you can calculate 1 score per second, local search will be inefficient. We generally say that anything below a 1000 is too low.

Comment: Also, the overhead of multi-threaded solver in OptaPlanner is not just in context switching. Even on machines with many cores, we still see that going over 4 move threads is gradually more and more inefficient. The synchronization we use simply isn't efficient enough to scale well for more than the recommended 4.

Comment: [unrelated] Hmmm... o.k., I'll do some testing with different numbers of threads on the 96-thread-machine and see what I can come-up with.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: That recommondation of max 4 move thread applies to the current verions of OptaPlanner 8.12. We will improve that signfinicantly in the future, by working on the sync mechanism.