# Ideal number of cores for multithreaded solving

Tags: optaplanner

I'm looking for a way to speed up the solver by adding more cores.

What is the ideal number of cores I can donate when configuring multithreaded solving?

According to this thread: [OptaPlanner, Score calculation speed will be too low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201962/optaplanner-score-calculation-speed-will-be-too-low?rq=1)

> the current best practice is to not go above 4 move threads, as the solver likely won't scale past that anyway

Are we really limited to 4 cores? If the ideal/optimal number of cores is 4/~4, is there other option for me to explore around in order to scale the solver, besides using partitioned search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threaded incremental solving does not scale linearly to the number of CPU cores; from a certain number (8 or 16) the performance is below what using 4 CPU cores can do.

Watch the score calculation speed and pick the number of CPU cores that gives you the best results.

There are also [other multi-threading options](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#multithreadedSolving) for OptaPlanner.

Last but not least, [benchmarking and tweaking the configuration](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/benchmarking-and-tweaking/benchmarking-and-tweaking.html) can bring better results than using more cores (of course, these two are not mutually exclusive).

Comment: All of the above is correct. Still, I would feel remiss if I did not add that there are often lower-hanging fruit in terms of solver performance. Are your constraints as fast as they can be? Have you eliminated all the score traps? If so, feel free to start thinking about parallelization.